# CHM help file not opening in windows

Tags: windows-7, regedit

I have shared some SAP related **chm** help files over the network with full read/write rights, but all clients are unable to see the contents of help files.

After search, I tried to fix it by using regedit. But still I am unable to see the chm contents. All clients are part of my domain mostly Windows 7/2008 (64bit).

The registry changes I made are as follows:

[image: Registry Edit-1]
[image: Registry Edit-2]

What could be the reason I'm unable to view the contents?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the file, does it have the security message regarding: "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect the computer." with the option to 'Unblock'?

Comment: I donot see any UNBLOCK option.
I even copied the whole folder locally, but still same situation.